# Http Request using Jquery

Tags: jquery, httprequest

I am using following code to make http request to the web server and it doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me the reason and how could do it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AddUser").click(function(){

  alert("Sending");
      $.post("http://10.200.208.18:1897/Channels/HttpChannel/Input",
      {
       CustomerId : "Ram"
       CustomerName : "Ram Kumar"
       AnualIncome : "120000"
       Country : "INDIA"
       Balance : "100"
       DOB : "1980-09-12T12:34:45"
      },
      function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Explain *doesn't work* in more detail. Does it throw errors?

Comment: Find the errors by using Firebug on Firefox or Google Chrome developers tools. You can press F12 and click on console to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the IP `http://10.200.208.18:1897` to the domain name `http://example.com:1897` or `http://localhost:1897`.

Also make sure that the **URL** is correct and that it has an available resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the ajax calls through your console.
If the params are being sent correctly they will show under the POST tab of a Ajax Request.
Also the URL /Channels/HttpChannel/Input is local or an external one?

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is missing commas at the end of each line (I added the required commas) so it's not valid javascript:

```
  {
   CustomerId : "Ram",
   CustomerName : "Ram Kumar",
   AnualIncome : "120000",
   Country : "INDIA",
   Balance : "100",
   DOB : "1980-09-12T12:34:45"
  },
```

You may also have a [same-origin security restriction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) problem where you can't make an ajax call to a different domain than the current web page.

Check the javascript error console of debugger console to see what other errors might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

commas after each value in the data section of the post

```
{
    CustomerId: "Ram",
    CustomerName: "Ram Kumar",
    AnualIncome: "120000",
    Country: "INDIA",
    Balance: "100",
    DOB: "1980-09-12T12:34:45"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://10.200.208.18:1897/Channels/HttpChannel/Input",
  data: {
     CustomerId : "Ram",
     CustomerName : "Ram Kumar",
     AnualIncome : "120000",
     Country : "INDIA",
     Balance : "100",
     DOB : "1980-09-12T12:34:45"
  },
  success: successFunction(),
  dataType: "JSON"
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fahad, it gives me error (OK,parsererror,objecterror). when i use dataType; Without dataType , i get success , but request not hitting the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** that this url `http://10.200.208.18:1897/Channels/HttpChannel/Input`
 returns the expected output or **it doesn't throw an exception**.

Just a suggestion how about using this instead, your code will be more readable

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
         CustomerId : "Ram",
         CustomerName : "Ram Kumar",
         AnualIncome : "120000",
         Country : "INDIA",
         Balance : "100",
         DOB : "1980-09-12T12:34:45"
    },
    url: "http://10.200.208.18:1897/Channels/HttpChannel/Input",
    /* this is optional if your data is of json type
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    */
    success: function (data) {
        //manipulate the data
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // show the error details or show a user friendly error message
        alert("Due to unexpected errors we were unable to load data");

    }
});
```

please refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for documentation